# Piping to different commands based on exit status in bash

Tags: bash

Trying to achive something like:

```
command | { [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0] == 0 ]] && cmd_pipe_success || cmd_pipe_failed ; }
```

e.g. piping to different commands, depending on the exit-status.

The above exmaple didn't works, e.g.:

```
command_ok() { sed 's/^/OK /'; }
command_no() { sed 's/^/NO /'; }

touch x
ls -l x 2>&1 | { [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} == 0 ]] && command_ok || command_no ; }
rm x
ls -l x 2>&1 | { [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} == 0 ]] && command_ok || command_no ; }
```

both prints `OK`, so in both cases runs the `command_ok`.

Is possible achieve to run the `command_no` when the exit-staus of `ls` is nonzero?

I know, it is possible to achieve like

```
command_ok() { sed 's/^/OK /'; return 0; }
command_no() { sed 's/^/NO /'; return 0; }

touch x
res=$(ls -l x 2>&1)
[[ $? == 0 ]] && command_ok <<<"$res" || command_no <<<"$res"

rm x
res=$(ls -l x 2>&1)
[[ $? == 0 ]] && command_ok <<<"$res" || command_no <<<"$res"
```

but i want **avoid** the helper variable, nor temp files. It is possible?

Comment: The pipe needs to be set up before the `command` has exited, right? How could you switch the destination of the pipe based on an exit status that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Just figured out - than it is nonsense, because **i can't know the exit-status** of the command, because it is still running...

Comment: If the shell runs all the components of a pipeline in the same shell, in theory something like `{ command1 & pid=$!; } | { wait $pid && command_ok || command_no; }` could work. POSIX doesn't forbid this, but I don't know of any shells that do this.

Comment: @chepner, I think $pid is substitued in the right side before the execution of the pipe.

Comment: Hmm, probably. In my theoretical shell, though, each command of the pipeline is processed from left to right, so `$pid` is set in component 1 before expansions in component 2 occur :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, there's no way to do this without getting a temp file involved: The pipe needs to be set up before the original command is finished running. However, doing it with a temp file is pretty easy:

```
TEMPFILE=$(mktemp)
if command > $TEMPFILE; then
  command_ok < $TEMPFILE
else
  command_no < $TEMPFILE
fi
rm $TEMPFILE
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, as processes connected with pipes run concurrently, not sequentially. In other words, as soon as you get the exit status of the first command, all the output would have been sent over the pipe already. A pipe always connects two running processes, and running processes don't have an exit status yet.

Answer (score 2):

Components of a pipeline run in parallel (and usually, in separate shells) , so there is no way to determine whether the first command succeeds or not before running the second.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the TRAP command. You can do different things based on the outcome of a command or return value of a script.

For example, you can say `trap 'echo 'Exiting...'; exit' SIGQUIT`

Here is a page full of examples, including some more involved ones that might be helpful: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-usingtraps/